# replace before and after a special character in sql

Tags: sql

My situation is as follows

I have a list of items which you need to remove some unnecessary things

is an example

```
4-Starred Ladybug of Doom RP 02-EN022
```

I need to remove 4 letters before the hyphen - and 5 after

You may be wondering why he did not just cut backwards

```
UPDATE mytable  
SET column = LEFT (column, LEN (column) -10)
```

There are other parts that have 3 before, after 4 -

However all have `-` in the middle

I thank the help

I need this result:

```
 4-Starred Ladybug of Doom
```

Comment: How do we know which characters you want to remove? Is there some kind of pattern to the text you want to remove, other than just the `-` character? For example, how do we know that `Doom` should stay, but `RP` should not?

Comment: Look up the functions section in you SQL manual.  Find the appropriate ones to use.  ...BUT, If you don't know what you are looking for, then just sit down and read about all of them.  It will be of great benefit to you to know what is available there I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with answering based on your question. In your example

```
4-Starred Ladybug of Doom RP 02-EN022
```

You said to remove 5 after `-` and 4 before. In that case result would be

```
4-Starred Ladybug of Doom R
```

---

To match your result I can do this

```
DECLARE @something VARCHAR(50) ='4-Starred Ladybug of Doom RP 02-EN022'

SELECT LEFT(@something,LEN(@something) - (CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@something),0)+6))
```

but this will only work when there are 6 characters to remove before `-`. When working with strings space is treated as 1 character, thus in your case you need to remove 4 letters and 2 spaces.

This code will keep everything before last 2 spaces.

```
DECLARE @something VARCHAR(50) ='4-Starred Ladybug of Doom RP 02-EN022'
SELECT LEFT(@something,LEN(@something) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@something),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@something))+1))
```